# retrieve appointment from OWA(on premises outlook web Access) using C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, office365

How to retrieve calendar meetings and appointments list from OWA(outlook web Access) using C#. without using exchange web services

Comment: The last time I looked there was extensive API documentation for Exchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Microsoft Graph Api:

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/user_list_events

Or Outlook Api:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/calendar-rest-operations

Simple googling will get you the above results...